# jquery hide hides and immediately displays again

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery is doing something strange for me: it just doesn't work and hides the div only for split a second. What am I doing wrong?

The code in question, as simple as can be.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Experiment</title>
<script type="text/javascript" 
           src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

        function doHiding() {
           $("div.thread").each(function() {
                    $(this).hide();
           });
        }


</script>
<a href="" onClick="doHiding()">Hide</a>

<div class="thread">I like trains.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using Chromium on Linux. I see the div dissapear for split a second, but it appears again immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 function doHiding() {
       $("div.thread").each(function() {
                $(this).hide();
       });
      return false;
    }
```

it is not hiding again it is the page that is being refreshed because `href=""` links to same page

NB: i guess you used `onClick="doHiding()"` for the sake of demo only (otherwise handle your event within jquery scope)

Comment: Oh. *facepalm* Of course. You are right. (I will accept this as a good answer as soon as SO will let me.)

Comment: i guess you used onClick="doHiding()" for the sake of demo only (otherwise handle your event within jquery scope) -- how to do that? I don't know this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing

```
<a href="" onClick="doHiding()">
```

into

```
<a href="#" onClick="doHiding()">
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/aVNuf/

Comment: thanks, mikakun was slightly faster so I gave the best answer to him

Answer (score 0):

try

```
href="#"
```

its work for this case

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `click event` in jquery `instead doing it inline`.

<kbd>http://jsbin.com/iseref/1/edit</kbd>

### html:

---

```
<a href="#">Hide</a>
<div class="thread">I like trains.</div>
```

---

### jQuery:

---

```
 $(function(){
    $('a').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     doHiding();
    });
 });
function doHiding() {
  $("div.thread").each(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
}
```